# Convert a Thread to a Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, invoke

I am trying to use .Net Task in the following code.

```
Thread hilo;
delegate void delegado(int valor);

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hilo = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Proceso1));
            hilo.Start();
        }
public void Proceso1()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
            {
                delegado MD = new delegado(Actualizar1);
                this.Invoke(MD, new object[] { i });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
public void Actualizar1(int valor)
        {
            ProgressBar1.Value = valor;

            int incremento= valor % 4;
            switch (incremento)
            {
                case 1: lblMensaje.Text = "Estamos procesando ."; break;
                case 2: lblMensaje.Text = "Estamos procesando .."; break;
                case 3: lblMensaje.Text = "Estamos procesando ..."; break;
                default: lblMensaje.Text = "Estamos procesando ...."; break;
            }
        }
```

**While the Task is running**, the textbox must be **updated** and also, when the **Task is terminated or canceled**, the textbox should **not be updated**.

And avoiding a similar message that interrupts the execution: **"The current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment"**

It will be used on ***desktop and web***.

Thanks, all kinds of help.

Comment: Since all `Proceso1` does is pushing `Actualizar1` to UI thread, it's not clear, what are you trying to achieve. There's no benefit from threads/tasks here.

Comment: Don't use `Invoke()` from a worker thread as it can lead to thread deadlock.  Instead use `BeginInvoke()`

Comment: ....anyway, spawning a thread that just ends up doing nothing but thread marshalling to the UI thread, then sleeping for 1 second is terribly wasteful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straight conversion to an asynchronous Task pattern:

```
public async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Proceso1();
}

private async Task Proceso1()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
    {
        Actualizar1(i);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

private void Actualizar1(int valor)
{
    ProgressBar1.Value = valor;

    int incremento = valor % 4;
    switch (incremento)
    {
        case 1: lblMensaje.Text = "Estamos procesando ."; break;
        case 2: lblMensaje.Text = "Estamos procesando .."; break;
        case 3: lblMensaje.Text = "Estamos procesando ..."; break;
        default: lblMensaje.Text = "Estamos procesando ...."; break;
    }
}
```

That said, I am unsure what this is accomplishing that you couldn't have just used a System.Windows.Forms.Timer to accomplish better.

Comment: Pretty sure the `Invoke()` is not required

Comment: It might be, the Task may be running on a Thread Pool thread, so we need the invoke just in case.  I suppose I should check InvokeRequired first however.

Comment: Perhaps. But don't use `Invoke()`, if anything use `BeginInvoke()`.  It's kinder to kittens

Comment: @BrandonKramer `InvokeRequired` will always be `false` in this code. Properly written code should never need `InvokeRequired`.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary I was under the impression that Tasks were run either on the current thread OR on the Thread Pool depending on what the Scheduler decides is more efficient.  Is it certain that Proceso1 will be running on the UI thread?

Comment: @BrandonKramer: Tasks returned from `async` are completely different. More in [my `async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).